# oracle apex query using a return value of select list and text_field in a where clause

Tags: oracle-apex

I have a simple select list `P5_MGR` the I need to pass the return value into a where clause for a sql select statement. `tSeries` that will then build a chart.

[image: overview]

I have this now in my where clause `WHERE MANAGER_ID =  :P5_MGR`  and it works but I would like to retain what was initially selected in P5_MGR. and you lose that because of the `Redirect and Set Value`.  I was hoping to get it to working with a DA, but I couldn't figure it out.

Answer (score 0):

One option is to make select list item **submit** when its value is changed. It means that - as it'll be used in `where` clause - chart will refresh, accepting newly selected list item value. You'd simply

```
where id = :P1_ID_SELECT_LIST_ITEM
```

(applying real column and item names, of course).

Comment: Sorry I should have been more clear, (I will try and update the initial post) Thats what I have now and it works, but I don't what to use that option as when it refreshes you lose what selection you selected in P5_MGR.

Comment: You said you used "Redirect and set value"; did you try with "Submit" I suggested? Or - as you also mentioned dynamic action - that would probably be a "Refresh tChart region".

Answer (score 0):

The typical way of approaching this is to create a DA on the page item that refreshes the chart region. There are 2 actions to take.

- Create a dynamic action on change of P5_MGR with a true action of type "Refresh" that refreshes the chart.
- Make sure the chart has `P5_MGR` in "Page Items to Submit"

This approach implements an ajax request that only refreshes part of your page, so there is no need to submit and re-render the page (that re-rendering is causing the "losing my selection" behaviour you're describing.